# Selection routine with dupes?

Tags: algorithm, selection, big-o, median-of-medians

I recently wrote a program after analyzing the k-th smallest element algorithm, first without the case of duplicates.

Now, however, I would like to analyze the expected asymptotic runtime for finding, say, the median of an array when there are exactly `j` duplicates. I haven't modified my code for such, and thus the performance slows down a bit because of the `j` duplicates.

I'm not sure how to begin? Can anyone point me towards such a recurrence relation?

I've derived the following, where n is the size of the input array

```
T(n) <= 1/2*T(3/4*n) + 1/2*T(n)
```

but am quite unclear how to proceed with duplicate keys involved.

Thanks

Comment: We cannot help you unless we have the function you are talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The randomized solution [as demonstrated here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15451-s07/www/lecture_notes/lect0125.pdf) is

```
 T(n) <= T(3/4*n) + n-1  =>  T(n) <= 4n
```

The complexity of the algorithm may depend on `j` but don't expect it to be miraculously less than linear time. Why? take a random array of size n/2, duplicate it completely and run the ideal algorithm for the problem with duplicates. You'll have

```
T(n) <= 4(n/2) => T(n) <= 2n
```

when each element is duplicated twice (exactly `n/2` duplicates)